# Can we define a time out for logic app - SQL Database connector

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way I can define a timeout for logic app sql database connector. 
I have a requirement to run a long running DB transaction as a step, wanted to do a feasibility analysis of this ask.

I refer the below doc could not really find a way to define a timeout property for a connector. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow patterns to extend the time of custom actions (by doing async processing) for actions that can last up to 90 days, but a single synchronous request can only remain open for 120 seconds as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config)

Comment: Is it still the case that running SQL queries or stored procedures from Logic App SQL connector is limited to 120 seconds?